# start background script to run a task then exit it

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I want to run `node task.js` which needs `node worker.js` to be started prior `task.js`. As soon as `node task.js` has finished i want to stop `node worker.js`

For now i've tried double-forking, like:

```
(node worker.js &) & node task.js
```

But it's not working very well, `worker.js` does not seems to be killed when `task.js` has completed. Moreover `task.js` stdout is visible only at the end.

One more thing, i'm running this script in a Makefile, something like:

```
task:
    (node worker.js &) & node task.js
```

EDIT: in accepted answer, working command to kill process is `pkill -f "node worker.js"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
node worker.js &
node task.js
pkill -9 worker.js
```

Comment: `pgrep` command does'nt seems to work here, process name is `node worker.js`

Comment: try using `kill -9` normal `kill` is sometimes ignored.

Comment: how about `pkill -9 node` ? May be node is the parent process for worker.js

Comment: not the best IMHO, as it will kill all node processes

Comment: If `pkill -9 worker.js` doesn't work, there will be no way of killing it without killing it's parent.

Comment: Even if it doesn't get killed by the command `pkill -9 worker.js` (not `pkill -9 "node worker.js"` ) , it will at least be stopped (being in a zombie/defunct state).

Comment: I have to say - I dislike `kill -9` as a default option. It can leave 'stuff' in an inconsistent state. If your process isn't exiting with a `SIGTERM` then that's really the problem that needs fixing.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is a little difficult. But you're right - it won't stop the process you started and backgrounded, because ... you didn't ask it to.

You can do this with `bash` job control mechanism - if you run `jobs -p` you should see a list of backgrounded processes and their pid. Unfortunately whilst that works with an interactive shell, it doesn't work so well in a shell script. Fortunately, `$!` is 'pid of last process started':

So what you need to do is:

```
node worker.js &
PID=$!
node task.js
kill $PID
```

This should kill the pid of `worker.js` once `task.js` is finished running.

Comment: You _might_ want to also add a sleep followed by a kill -9 $PID (which will be a no-op if the kill succeeded but guarantees[1] that it will be killed if it ignored the default kill.  [1] Technically not true; on SGI  Unix (and I believe Linux but I have only seen it on the former), if something is NFS mounted and NFS dies, you can end up with a process that ignores kill -9... but at that point, you're kind of hosed anyways.

Comment: Possibly, but I'm not sure I like the implication of the race condition.

Comment: Is that referring to if the first kill works and then it's possible another process gets the same PID which then gets the kill -9 signal? I had thought about that (and that technically even the vanilla way you suggested would seem to have the same theoretical concern if the worker finishes a lot quicker and the task goes on for a while), but believe that assuming PID's are assigned sequentially and use at least a 15 bit number, this shouldn't happen unless something like a unconfined fork bomb is happening, in which case, see about comment about being hosed anyways.